# How MySql can retrieve and display photos with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file, variables

I have a PHP site where I have uploaded 10 pictures locally. The pictures are saved in the `./images` folder and also resampled to a `./thumbnails` folder. I use this query to extract 7 photo file names from the database.

```
$imgQuery = "SELECT FileName, Title, Description FROM PICTURE WHERE OwnerID='$id' LIMIT 0,7";
```

The database saves `PictureID`(PK), `OwnerID`(UNQ, my id is 2), `FileName`(stores the file name) and `Title` for the picture and `Description` for the picture. I use this method of transferring 7 photo filenames, title and description to an array. But how can I extract them from my `./thumbnails` folder and display them on my PHP page?

```
if($imgResult = mysqli_query($link, $imgQuery))
{
 while($imgRow = mysqli_fetch_row($imgResult))
 {

    $filename[] = $imgRow[0];
    $title[] = $imgRow[1];
    $description[] = $imgRow[2];
 }
}
```

Here is where I am displaying the thumbnails `t1` in the body. I would like to know how can assign the files retrieved by my database to these variables. The description changes based on which name i

```
$num = count($filename);
while($i < $num)
{
$i = 0;
print <<<photo
<body>
<form action='MyAlbum.php' method='post'>
    <table>
        <tr><td colspan='7' ><h2 align='center'><?php echo $name;?>'s Album</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan='7' ><?php echo $title[$i];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan='5' ><?php echo $filename[$i]; ?></td><td colspan='2'><?php echo $description[$i];?> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php  echo $filename[0];?></td> <td><?php  echo $filename[1];?></td> <td><?php echo $filename[2];?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $filename[3]; ?></td><td><?php echo $filename[4]; ?></td> <td><?php echo $filename[5]; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $filename[6]; ?></td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
$i++;
</body>
</html>

photo;
 }
```

Comment: You're using `mysqli` so please use the [proper SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) supported by it. You have no excuse for this SQL injection bug.

Comment: mysqli is what I am taught to use. It is suppose to work well locally with AMPPS. Or do you mean i need to use some `stmt`

Comment: I mean you should **NEVER** see things like `OwnerID='$id'` in your query. Instead you should have `OwnerID=?` and then call `bind_param` to assign values as in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). What you're doing is extremely reckless and will eventually get you into serious trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on two things you don't say: the filename that in full resolution is saved in "FileName", what name has assigned inside `thumbnails`? And does `FileName` contain the full path, or only the "bare" file name?

```
// If
// FileName = "/images/LenaSjooblom.jpg", thumbnail is "./thumbnails/LenaSjooblom.jpg"
// Then
$Thumbnail = './thumbnails/' . basename($FileName);

// If
// FileName = "LenaSjooblom.jpg", thumbnail is "./thumbnails/LenaSjooblom.jpg"
// Then
$Thumbnail = './thumbnails/' . $FileName;

// If
// FileName = "/images/LenaSjooblom.jpg", thumbnail is "./thumbnails/12.jpg"
// Then
$Thumbnail = './thumbnails/' . $PictureID . '.jpg';
```

The code above you put into the same loop, e.g:

```
$filename[] = $imgRow[0];
$title[] = $imgRow[1];
$description[] = $imgRow[2];

// ADDED THUMBNAIL - hypothesis 1
$thumbnail[] = "./thumbnails/".basename($imgRow[0]);
```

and could display with

```
<img src="$thumbnail[$i]" />
```

### Update

If your thumbnail is the duplicate of filename, then you need nothing else - you can just change the HTML, and add:

```
<img src="./thumbnails/$filename[$i]" />
```

and it will instruct the browser to fetch a filename with the same name of the image, *but from the thumbnails directory*. (If it doesn't work at first, check the path; in a pinch, use an absolute path, such as "`/thumbnails/$filename[$i]`" ).

Comment: The FileName in database is just strictly the file name. The file name in the `./images` folder is the same as `./thumbnails` folder.

Comment: That's convenient! Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks I put the loop in the wrong place before. So this should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
<img src="<?php echo $filePath;?>" alt="some_text">
```

Just make sure that the variable you have for $filePath is the url to the actual image in the folder

Comment: If I use that then I would have to scan my `./thumbnails` directory and search for the filenames that are the same `$filenames` as my select query. Which is my last resort, and very complicated.

Comment: Just save the file path in your database. <img src="./thumbnails/<?php echo $imageName;?>"